# Is there a way to get the read current values from a Keithley SourceMeter onto my computer?

Tags: python, instrumentation

I am performing a sweep, and all works well! Except for when I try to print the current values that it's reading... all it prints is the number of characters of the SPCI command I used. Here is the code:

```
import pyvisa
import time
import serial

 
# configure the serial connections (the parameters differs on the device you are connecting to)
ser = serial.Serial()
ser.port = 'COM3'

ser.baudrate = 9600
ser.open()
ser.isOpen


###Sweep
numberofiterations = 10
stepsize = 0.05
voltage = 0
currents = []
voltages = []

ser.write(str.encode('*RST' + '\r\n'))
ser.write(str.encode(':OUTP ON'+'\r\n'))

    
for iterations in range(numberofiterations):
    #record voltage
    voltages.append(round(voltage,5))
    #supply voltage
    ser.write(str.encode(':SOUR:FUNC VOLT'+'\r\n'))
    ser.write(str.encode(':SOUR:VOLT:MODE FIX'+'\r\n'))
    ser.write(str.encode(':SOUR:VOLT:RANG 20'+'\r\n'))
    ser.write(str.encode(':SOUR:VOLT:LEV '+str(voltage)+'\r\n'))

    #wait 
    time.sleep(1)

    #measure current
    ser.write(str.encode(':SENS:FUNC "CURR"'+'\r\n'))
    ser.write(str.encode(':SENS:CURR:PROT 10e-1'+'\r\n'))
    ser.write(str.encode(':SENS:CURR:RANG 10e-1'+'\r\n'))
    ser.write(str.encode(':SENS:CURR:RANG:AUTO ON'+'\r\n'))
    current = ser.write(str.encode(':READ?'+'\r\n')) #measure current
    currents.append(current) #record current
 
    #increase voltage
    voltage += stepsize
    

#Print out values
for current in range(len(currents)):
    print(currents[current])

for voltage in range(len(voltages)):
    print(voltages[voltage])
```

Specifically, this is the line that's messing up my code:

```
current = ser.write(str.encode(':READ?'+'\r\n')) #measure current
```

Why is it not measuring the current on the computer? The Keithley SourceMeter is measuring it properly as the currents are showing on its screen... I just can't get these values onto the computer. What is wrong here?

Thank you!

Comment: You are only ever using ser.write () Did you mean to use ser.read() after a write?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ser.write` writes bytes to the serial port, and simply reports how many bytes were written. You'll need to read the response from the instrument using `ser.read` (which reads one byte) or some helper function (your own or library-provided), which can understand the response format of an SCPI command.

According to [this reference](http://literature.cdn.keysight.com/litweb/pdf/ads2001/esgprog/1prep8.html), it looks like the SCPI response is delimited with a newline, so you should be able to write a command using `ser.write` and then call [`ser.readline()`](https://pyserial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pyserial_api.html#serial.Serial.readline) to read a whole line of instrument output, up to a newline character. Of course, you'll get a response back in the SCPI format, so you'll need to parse it to obtain your circuit observations.

Note that if you get in an odd state where the instrument is not writing output, but you're in a `readline` call waiting for a response, your program may lock up. Setting a timeout for the serial port will be helpful. I'm not familiar enough with the protocol to know when this might occur.

Comment: Thank you, but would you be able to provide an example? I am a little confused about how to implement this!

Comment: @Stella I don't have an SCPI device at my desk so I can't come up with a plausible full example. Start by just calling `ser.readline()` every time you expect a response from the instrument, and print the output. You'll then see what the instrument is reporting, and might be able to come up with a way to parse it.

Comment: Thank you so much, I am now getting a response in SPCI format like you said it would be :). I still need to figure out how to parse it, but this is definitely progress so thank you!

Comment: @Stella No problem; if you do run into trouble parsing it, having examples would be very helpful in a follow-up question. I can imagine you might be able to use a combination of `split` to break the string up by delimiters, grabbing the parts you need, and then converting them using `float(...)` or something. It's probably even easier if you write the parsing code to only handle the specific outputs you have, rather than something fully generalized.

Comment: Alright, I will probably end up asking because this is super new to me Lol.  But, I will for sure keep your advice in mind :)!

Comment: Hey, I am really stuck on how to parse these return values. So, what ended up working is:   ser.write(str.encode(':READ?'+'\r\n'))
    current = bytes.decode(ser.read(5))                                                                                       However, the current is 2.9987mA and it's returning '46997'                                                 Some of the return values are even like '7,+1' . Do you have any idea how to convert these? Thanks sm

Comment: @Stella I don't know the protocol well enough to be sure and I don't have an SCPI instrument to test with. Are you sure those are the exact bytes returned from the instrument? You might also be getting acknowledgements for prior commands, so keep reading as much as you can and printing it out to see what you can find. Remember that if you write a command, the instrument responds, you write another command, the instrument responds again, and you read, you'll get the response to the *first* command and may need to read more bytes to get the response to the second command.

Comment: @Stella `7,+1` looks like you might have part of a response, or something spanning across two subsequent responses.